# How can I use atg-workflow from .wdl file?

Tags: atg

I'm trying to execute importing versioned data from Publishing/base/sample-code/ca-import-sample-code.jar but it doesn't work cause it can't recognize import.wdl in config directory. Which steps can be applied to use "atg-workflow" from .wdl file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place your `.wdl` on this `configpath` folder, `/atg/registry/data/epubworflows/Content Administration/FILE.wdl`

And, on your `.properties` file you set the property that stores the workflow file name like this `workflowName=/Content Administration/import.wdl`